# Ember filtering async data on load

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have the route `/bets` with a component to display bets filtered by future dates. The route template also has a link to route `/bets/new` where the user can add new bets. Each bet has a `belongsTo` relationship to `User`.

My problem is that my bets doesn't show up in the component even though I can see in Ember Inspector that the data is loaded. It does show up when I add a new bet through the form in `/bets/new` though.

My reasoning was that since the data is async, it doesn't load until I request it by pushing a new bet, but I can't get my head around it.

*bets.hbs*

```
{{outlet}}

 {{#link-to 'bets.new' class="btn btn-default"}}
   {{fa-icon "plus"}} New bet
 {{/link-to}}

 {{#upcoming-bets bets=model.bets}}
 {{/upcoming-bets}}
```

*bets.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model () {
    return this.store.findRecord('user', this.get('session.currentUser.uid'));
  }

});
```

*upcoming-bets.hbs*

```
<h2>Upcoming bets:</h2>

{{#each upcomingBets as |bet|}}

<div class="bet">
    <h3>{{bet.homeTeam}} vs {{bet.awayTeam}}</h3>
    <p>
      <small>{{moment-format bet.eventDate 'MMMM Do'}}</small>
    </p>
    <p>
      Bet type: {{bet.type}}
    </p>
    <p>
      Bet: {{bet.bet}}
    </p>
    <p>
      Stake: {{bet.stake}}
    </p>
    <p>
      User: {{bet.user}}
    </p>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" {{action "deleteBet" bet}}>{{fa-icon "trash"}}</button>
</div>

{{else}}

<p>
  You don't have any upcoming bets. Maybe {{#link-to 'bets.new'}}add one?{{/link-to}}
</p>

{{/each}}
```

*upcoming-bets.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  upcomingBets: function() {

    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    return this.get('bets').filter(function(bet){
      return bet.get('eventDate') > today;
    });
  }.property('bets.@each'),

  actions: {
    deleteBet: function(bet){
      bet.destroyRecord();
    }
  }

});
```

*new.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  actions: {

    addBet() {
      var newBet = this.store.createRecord('bet', {
        created: new Date(),
        sport: this.get('selectedSport.name'),
        league: this.get('league'),
        homeTeam: this.get('homeTeam'),
        awayTeam: this.get('awayTeam'),
        type: this.get('type'),
        bet: this.get('bet'),
        stake: this.get('stake'),
        odds: this.get('odds'),
        eventDate: this.get('eventDate'),
      });

      // Save user as well as bet
      var user = this.get('user');
      user.get('bets').addObject(newBet);

      newBet.save().then(function(){
        return user.save();
      });
    }
  }

});
```

*user.js*

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  email: DS.attr('string'),
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  bets: DS.hasMany('bet', { async: true })
});
```

*bet.js*

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  created: DS.attr('date'),
  sport: DS.attr('string'),
  league: DS.attr('string'),
  homeTeam: DS.attr('string'),
  awayTeam: DS.attr('string'),
  type: DS.attr('string'),
  bet: DS.attr('string'),
  stake: DS.attr('number'),
  odds: DS.attr('number'),
  eventDate: DS.attr('date'),
  win: DS.attr('boolean', {defaultValue: false}),
  closed: DS.attr('boolean', {defaultValue: false}),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user', { async: true })
});
```

I appreciate any pointers. Thank you!

***Update 22 nov 2016***

I've tried making things simpler and more clean by moving the filtering part to a controller as well as making the filter itself simpler by just matching a string. I still have the exact same issue - nothing gets rendered until I add a new bet at which point the filter works as intended and the correct bets show up. I've also had a hard time researching the issue as most examples with filtering out there waits for some sort of action before the filtering is done, for example typing something in an input field. I need the filtering to be done on load.

Here are my updated files:

*bets.hbs*

```
{{outlet}}

{{#link-to 'bets.new' class="btn btn-default"}}
  {{fa-icon "plus"}} New bet
{{/link-to}}

  {{#each upcomingTest as |bet|}}
  <p>
    {{bet.homeTeam}}
  </p>
  {{/each}}
```

*controllers/bets.js*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  upcomingTest: function() {

    var team = 'EXAMPLE';

    return this.get('model.bets').filterBy('homeTeam', team);

  }.property('model.bets.@each')

});
```

***Update 23 nov 2016***
So I think I've proved that the issue has to do with me wanting to filter data that has a relationship to the model and isn't being loaded directly in the route. I tried using the exact same filter on data that I loaded directly in the route and that works great, even directly on load.

Comment: Can you please provide your 'user' model definition as well? From what I can see, the first time you load the bets for the user is in the `addBet()` function

Comment: I updated my question with both of the concerned model definitions. I thought they got loaded in the `upcomingBets()` function aswell? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried including the relationship in the find call? `return this.store.findRecord('user', this.get('session.currentUser.uid'), {include: 'bets'});`

Comment: @Beno Thx for the suggestion but that didn't seem to make any difference unfortunately.

Comment: Side note: `'model.bets.@each'` is not valid. It should be `'model.bets.[]'`